# How to control the exact format of scientific notation in a Python format string?

Tags: python, scientific-notation

By my question I mean, I have a few numbers ranging from `0.6e9` to `3.6e9`. I am already using `f"foo {number:.1E} bar"` to achieve scientific formatting in printing/display of f-strings, however this has the issue that `0.6e9` is "shortened" to `6.0e8`, which is not what I want.

I realise that, technically, it is a correct answer but for display purposes and readability I believe it would be better served as `0.6e9`, to be consistent with the others.

**To be clear what I want is to control the power of 10 used in scientific formatting.**
*Is this something one can easily control or would it require a custom function?*

Comment: Where exactly? The ticks, a label, some format string you pass to matplotlib? Please give a minimal example of where you want this to happen, preferably if this is a plot a plot with some numbers as a short example.

Comment: Please attach some code so that a better solution, relating with your program, can be given.

Comment: @kabanus Anywhere. The formatting is being done by the standard python formatting notation independently of where it will be used. Even a simple `print()` line. (e.g. type `print(f"{10000:.1e}")` into a python console.) In my particular case I've used it in the `label` argument of a `pyplot` plot, but it's just an f-string.

Comment: I have amended your question to make that clear - the matplotlib mention is a bit of a red herring since it has it's own formatting suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention this is just an f-string, in your particular example where the range is limited this may suffice to have a conforming format string:

```
f'{number/1e9:.1f}e9'
```

Comment: Clever! I've adjusted it to meet my needs in a matplotlib plot label as `fr"{number/1e9:.1f}$\times 10^9$"` giving me exactly what I hoped for, thanks!

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 Even better with the tex!